# Is there a linear transformation on $\mathbb{R^3}$ whose image and kernel are the same?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a linear transformation on $\mathbb R^3$ (the usual 3-dimensional vector space) whose image and kernel are the same?

How it can be same if their addition must be 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

Suppose Image=Kernel $\implies$ $r=\text{dim (Image)}=\text{dim (Kernel)}$. Then by Rank Nullity Theorem, $r+r=3$ which has non integer solutions, hence a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you I also thought that